# When I submit the contact form its shows error in react js

Tags: reactjs, form-submit

When I submit the contact form its shows error like error sending message.
Please help me is there any mistake in my code. I am new in react js.
This is the code i have used. please help me is there any logical or syntax mistake in this.

```
import React, { FormEvent, ReactElement } from 'react';
import { noop } from 'rxjs';
import { EmailData } from '../../../models/i-email-data';
import { EmailInput, MessageInput, NameInput, SubjectInput } from './';



  interface Props {
        onSubmit: (data: EmailData) => Promise<any>;
    }

    *type* State = EmailData;

    export class ContactForm extends React.Component<Props, State> {
        public state: State = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            subject: '',
            message: '',
        };

        public render(): ReactElement {
            const { name, email, subject, message } = this.state;
            return (
                <>
                    <h3 className='contact-form__title'>Send a Message</h3>
                    <form className='form' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <NameInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={name} />
                        <EmailInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={email} />
                        <SubjectInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={subject} />
                        <MessageInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={message} />
                        <div className='contact-form__btn-wrapper'>
                            <button className='contact-form__submit'> Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </>
            );

import React, { FormEvent, ReactElement } from 'react';
import { noop } from 'rxjs';
import { EmailData } from '../../../models/i-email-data';
import { EmailInput, MessageInput, NameInput, SubjectInput } from './';

interface Props {
    onSubmit: (data: EmailData) => Promise<any>;
}

type State = EmailData;

export class ContactForm extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    public state: State = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        subject: '',
        message: '',
    };

    public render(): ReactElement {
        const { name, email, subject, message } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <h3 className='contact-form__title'>Send a Message</h3>
                <form className='form' onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
                    <NameInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={name} />
                    <EmailInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={email} />
                    <SubjectInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={subject} />
                    <MessageInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={message} />
                    <div className='contact-form__btn-wrapper'>
                        <button className='contact-form__submit'> Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </>
        );
    }

    private handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>): void => {
        const { value, name } = event.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value } as any);
    };

    private onSubmit = async (e: FormEvent): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            e.preventDefault();
            await this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
            this.setState({ name: '', email: '', subject: '', message: '' });
        } catch (e) {
            noop();
        }
    };
```

This is the code i have used. please help me is there any logical or syntax mistake in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your `Props` interface I guess you're passing an `onSubmit` callback as a prop.

If that's the case you need to extract `onSubmit` from `this.props`, so the following doesn't fail.

```js
<form className='form' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
```

Edit 1: You need to pass your state in order to pass your form's state to the parent component

Change it to:

```js
<form 
  className='form'
  onSubmit={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
  }}
>
```

Edit 2: I see you're missing `handleInputChange` as well.

A quick implementation of `handleInputChange` would look like this:

```js
handleInputChange = (name) => ({ target }) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [name]: target.value
  });
}
```

And you could call it like so:

```js
<NameInput onChange={this.handleInputChange('name')} value={name} />
<EmailInput onChange={this.handleInputChange('email')} value={email} />
```

Comment: i have changed onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>. how can i run the changes? does i need to clear any cache or just to refresh the browser page.Iam sorry that iam new in react.

Comment: You're missing the `handleInputChange` implementation, I've edited the answer to include one. If you created the project with create-react-app it should update automatically on save, otherwise refresh the page or re-run the project.

Comment: By the way I think you still need to implement an `onSubmit` as well in order to pass the state of the form to the parent component.

Comment: i have added
 private handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>): void => {
        const { value, name } = event.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value } as any);
    };

    private onSubmit = async (e: FormEvent): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            e.preventDefault();
            await this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
            this.setState({ name: '', email: '', subject: '', message: '' });
        } catch (e) {
            noop();
        }
    };
}

Comment: That's seems right. Because we didn't pass the state to `onSubmit`. I also made a change to the answer.

Comment: now i have change my code. could you please take a look and  please suggest the change

Comment: @IoannisPotouridis good answer but I think you need to change `onChange={this.handleInputChange('email')}` to be `onChange={() => this.handleInputChange('email')}` otherwise it'll fire immediately? upvoting tho as seems good

Comment: @RedBaron No it won't, look again ;-)

Comment: @RedBaron, I mean it will be called but it will create a closure at first call.

Comment: By the way, if you go this way you still need to alter the handler and pass the event in order to get the value, `onChange={(event) => this.handleInputChange('email', event)}`

Answer (score 0):

there are a few issues with your code.

firstly you have no function called `onSubmit` so when you submit the form it's going to error coz it doesn't know this function.
`<form className='form' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>`

you need to create a function like this:

```
onSubmit = () => {
// do stuff in here
}
```

there is also no function called: `handleInputChange` so you need to create this too, like so:

```
handleInputChange = () => {
// do stuff in here
}
```

Comment: now i have change my code. could you please take a look and please suggest the change

Comment: use Ioannis's answer